# Kendo DropDownList Change event

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo DropDownList with the id SapProject_Id, when user changes its value I need to fire onChange, but this needs to be done in jquery not when I define Kendo DropDownList.

I have tried following code which is not working:

```js
var sapProject = $("#SapProject_Id").data("kendoDropDownList");
sapProject.change = onChange;

function onChange() {
    alert(1);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how it is failing? Have you tried using a javascript debugger such as Firebug in FireFox or the Chrome developer tools?

Comment: @Jon Yes I have, the onChange function is never called even though it is set. Is there any other event to call when you change KendoDropDown selection ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is:

```js
var sapProject = $("#SapProject_Id").data("kendoDropDownList").bind("change", onChange);
```

Answer (score 1):

For future views of this question, a cleaner way to do this is to use the `change` event in the declaration, like so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdown = $("#dropdown-id").kendoDropDownList({
        change: dropdownOnChange
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");

    function dropdownOnChange(e) {
        console.log('sap has been changed');
    }
});
```

You can find the telerik documentation for the events here (scroll to the bottom): https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist

Comment: It states in the question that he cannot put the event on the control when he creates the control.  He doesn't say why but that makes this invalid as a solution.